# React Native createSwitchNavigator with not resetting stack after switch the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, native

In the documentation is written: "The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time. **By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away.** This is the exact behavior that we want from the authentication flow."

Is any way to override default behavior to not reset the stacks when the switch happened?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Tab navigator` and specify a `Stack navigator` for each tab.

If you don't want to keep the tabs, you can hide it too.

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeNavigator,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarVisible: false,
      }),
    },
  },
);
```